# 100% height not working on one of two divs

Tags: html, css

I have three divs one main and two in it. Inside the main div is navbar and content div, which contains the form with textarea. Textarea is only vertical resizable. Content and navbar have min-height: 100%, main has min-height: 1200px. The height of main and content divs is changing by textarea size (thats what I want), but navbar has still 0px and is "invisible".

```css
.navbar {
 width: 250px;
 min-height: 100%;
 position: relative;
 background-color: #121212;
 float: left; 
}
.main {
 margin: auto;
 min-width: 1200px;
 float: left;
}
.content {
 width: 950px;
 min-height: 100%;
 background-color: #1c1c1c;
 color: white;
 float: left;
}
form {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 float: left;
}
textarea {
 min-height: 297px;
 resize: vertical;
 width: 800px;
 height: 770px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
   <div class="navbar">
      <!-- some links -->
   </div>
   <div class="content">
      <form>
         <textarea name="article">
         </textarea>
      </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

How can I make navbar same height as content?

Comment: You mention min-height: 1200px, but I see min-width:1200px. Is that intentional?

Comment: Try 100vh ; for 100% height

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `min-height: 100%` on content that can change the height of the parent (i.e. it's within the flow of the parent, not absolutely positioned) obviously comes with the problem that it can cause the height to infinitely increase. If `min-height` is `100%` and you have `padding: 10px` too, then the height of the child will increase, increasing the parent height and causing a loop.

As such, adding `min-height: 100%` will not work.

It's perhaps better to use `flex` for setting the height, such that you have `display: flex; align-items: stretch` on the parent. The `align-items: stretch` will cause the child elements of that parent to 'stretch; to the same height.

For example:

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: space-between;
  ...
}
```

The `justify-content: space-between` can also be changed to suit.

A complete guide to flex can be found [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: I deleted my answer, because this one is enough.